# how to make a dynamic photos viewer in php?

Tags: php, mysql

**dynamic photos ** make a dynamic photos viewer in PHP with time 
**dynamic photos ** make a dynamic photos viewer in PHP with time 
**dynamic photos ** make a dynamic photos viewer in PHP with time 
**dynamic photos ** make a dynamic photos viewer in PHP with time

`

```
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            switch ($id) {
                    case  '1';
                        echo "<img src=12.jpg width=100% height=100%>" ;
                        break;
                    case  '2';
                        echo "<img src=13.jpg width=100% height=100%>" ;
                        break;
                    case  '3';
                        echo "<img src=14.jpg width=100% height=100%>" ;
                        break;
                    case  'all';
                    for($i=12;$i<=14;$i++)
                    {
                        echo "<img src=$i.jpg width=100% height=100%>" ;
                    }

                        break;
                    default;
                        echo "Sorry No command found";
                }

        }
    ?>`
```

Comment: Please, rewrite your question. What is the problem and what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of POSTING the ID you can use rand()

```
$id = rand(1,4);
switch ($id) {
                case  '1';
                    echo "<img src=12.jpg width=100% height=100%>" ;
                    break;
                case  '2';
                    echo "<img src=13.jpg width=100% height=100%>" ;
                    break;
                case  '3';
                    echo "<img src=14.jpg width=100% height=100%>" ;
                    break;
                case  '4'; //All
                for($i=12;$i<=14;$i++)
                {
                    echo "<img src=$i.jpg width=100% height=100%>" ;
                }

                    break;
                default;
                    echo "Sorry No command found";
}
```